# holding payments with paypal like a credit card hold feature

Tags: .net, paypal

Dear stackoverflow members,

I'm a developer who wants to implement an online payment service (this is my first time working on a custom payment service module) for one of our clients, and they have suggested to use PayPal.

The scenario I have is like this:

The website will offer users to create projects they need funding to complete, the project owner should specify how much funding he needs and the time needed to collect this fund:
Example: "**User-1**" creates a new project Called "**Project-1**", he needs "**$1000**" to complete his project, and the time to collect this fund is "**1 week**".

Now other users can help (support) this guy by donating money to his project in different amounts: "$1", "$10", "$100", etc ...

What I need to implement using PayPal services is to hold the money from the "**Supporters**" in their accounts or any place, and after the "**1 week**" period has finished for collecting funds, the system will evaluate if the target budget has been reached or not, this means if "**Project-1**" fund raising reached "**$1000**" or not.

If the fund was successful (it reached "**$1000**") the money will be deducted from the supporters (donators) accounts and sent to the project owner "**User-1**" (there will be fees for PayPal and the system), but if the fund was a failure, the money will not be deducted and the supporters (donators) will have there money back (remove the hold on this money).

Is this something that can be done with PayPal services? or shall I investigate another approach?

I tried and searched allot in PayPal documentations and many articles, but they all refer to direct payments and refunding operations, this will cost the system money since PayPal will deduct the fees on paying and refunding.

I really appreciate any help on this matter.

Best Regards

Comment: seems you want to develop a new feature for PayPal, isn't it? You can't avoid the existing mechanism & charges.

Comment: I don't know about PayPal, but [**Kickstarter**](http://www.kickstarter.com/) has that payment model and they use [Amazon FPS](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/) to request a transfer and transfer when the project is funded. 
From all the negative feedback on PayPal from so many members, I would **not use them** for your project!

Comment: thanks, I will look into Amazon FPS

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does support the feature of Authorization. Basically you take the Authorization from the user for the amount you wish like $10, $100 etc., as above and then you can charge the user later using the authorization. You can do the authorization with PayPal Account as well as Credit Card. Detailed write-up is available here.

Using PayPal ExpressCheckout : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleAuthPayment-curl-etc/

Using Credit Card and DirectPayment : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/authorizations/

Hope it helps.

Comment: The links are not working..please udpate if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization and Capture could be useful here, but this sounds like a project better suited for [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_adaptivepayments.pdf).  Specifically [Preapproval](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/preapproval-api-operation) and [Pay](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation), which are covered in Chapters 8 and 6 respectively in that PDF documentation.

The Adaptive Payments platform opens up PayPal in ways that Authorization and Capture don't and can be very useful in projects like this.

It's basically the PayPal version of the Amazon Flexible Payments platform that was mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I was looking into Adaptive Payments platform from PayPal, I'm trying to implement a POC to see if this can cover my needs, thanks for the lead :)

Comment: hi @mabuyasin how's everything going? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Crowd-funding like sites PayPal has [this document](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/crowdfunding/)